# Access request object from within django admin's authenticate()

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Is this anyhow possible to access the **request object** from within the django admin's **authenticate()** in custom auth backend?

The reason for this is I want to keep and re-use the user's password (or a  Kerberos ticket - not sure yet) to authorize an operation in another system, which uses the same LDAP backend. For this purpose I wanted to use request.session - but it doesn't seem to be accessible, at least not the easy way.

If there's any other possibility to pass a value from the auth to the model, I'd be happy to get a suggestion as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a bad idea to store raw password in session for security reasons, but some ideas (just ideas, never tried it):

1. Access session directly https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views

Make sure your session won't be flushed by `django.contrib.auth.login`. See details in implementation.

2. `user_logged_in` signal has access to request and user object.

`user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)`

Looks like you can add attribute to `user` object inside `authentication` backend method and later attach it to session.